# Renderizar uma parte de um documento PDF para um arquivo de imagem

Tags: php

Boa dia Pessoal!
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função php que renderiza uma parte do arquivo pdf para um arquivo de imagem. Existe a função ImageMagick, mas não estou muito certo disso.

Comment: Você precisa gerar ou manipular o pdf e depois converter para imagem usando `php`?

Comment: Faço o upload do pdf para uma pasta, mas o caminho da pasta salvo no banco de dados. Gostaria só de renderizar apenas uma imagem do arquivo pdf para ser exibida no navegador usando php.

Comment: Vou elaborar uma resposta

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver seu problema utilizei o pacote [*SPATIE*](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) disponível no *github*.

Só realizar a instalação do pacote via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) conforme documentação do pacote.

Segue código:

```
<?php

use Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf as Render;

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$pdf_path = __DIR__ . '/pdf/file.pdf';
$images_path = __DIR__ . '/pdf/images/';

if (!file_exists($images_path)) {
    echo printf('Path %s não encontrado', $images_path);
    die;
}

if (!file_exists($pdf_path)) {
    echo printf('Path %s não encontrado', $pdf_path);
    die;
}

$pdf_to_image = new Render($pdf_path);

$image = $pdf_to_image->setPage(3)
    ->setOutputFormat('png')
    ->saveImage($images_path . date('now'));

if (!$image) {
    echo 'Erro ao renderizar PDF';
    die;
}

echo 'Sucesso ao renderizar PDF';
```

Obs.:

- Utilizei o `date('now')` para gerar o nome do arquivo
- Atenção a estrutura de pastas

  ```
  Projeto
  -> pdf
      ->images
  -> vendor
  ```
- Os arquivos `composer.json` e `index.php` estão na raiz do projeto